# Check CAML query OrderBy is not working

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, caml

The below code returns the correct data but the data is not being sorted ascending. Does it look correct?

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Query><View><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Type='Text' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" + 
            "<Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>");
```

I have tried it with and without the `<Query></Query>` tags and it still does not work.  I have tried just the OrderBy bits and nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View` and `Query` nodes are in wrong order.

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Type='Text' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" + 
            "<Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>");
```